# Euler summation to 1/2 - 1/4 schema

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was reading this article "[1 − 2 + 3 − 4 +](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%C2%B7_%C2%B7_%C2%B7)" on Wikipedia, when i saw the following [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Pm1234_Euler.svg).

I've never seen this kind of representation before. Can someone please explain me how it works ? Is there any standards ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a description here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pm1234_Euler.svg of what is meant

Comment: I read that description, but it still a bit confused. Moreover i still don't know if this kind of schematics is often used, and if there is standards i could find.

Comment: From what I remember from [Carl Bender's course](http://www.perimeterscholars.org/328.html) grouping is usually not valid unless it preserves the order(and some other conditions which I don't remember). For instance, consider this series: 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +...; where grouping is clearly not going to give the correct answer. A good textbook I know about these topics is Carl Bender's book [Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers I](http://books.google.com/books/about/Advanced_Mathematical_Methods_for_Scient.html?id=1sPymwEACAAJ). Sorry for long comment.

Comment: I think the picture is intended just as a pedagogical tool in this article.  What do you not understand about it? The top part is simply a graphical representation of the series. The next part shows what happens when you put half of every term into the next term. Then you see a representation of the series $\frac 12 -\frac 12 \ldots$. And so on.

Comment: @Ali, we know that the original series thus does not converge. Euler summation gives a value to it anyway. The picture illustrates the definition of Euler summation.

Comment: @FanOfFourier Obviously. Also, the videos of Carl Bender lectures can be found [here](http://pirsa.org/C11025)